# How can I tape drywall joints at the ceiling with existing texture?

Tags: drywall, texture, gap

I am redoing my subbasement. Originally the inside corner where the wall meets the ceiling was not taped and jointed. Some floor trim was used as a poor man's version of crown molding, and it is hideous. [image: With Trim on]

I am taking down the trim and wanting to fill in the gaps where the joints were not properly done. Both the wall and the ceiling have been textured. Is there a way to properly do the joint without having the scrape off the texture?

[image: With Trim Removed]

Answer (score 1):

Or you can caulk the joints and smooth it out. Use a caulk you can paint over when dry.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. Texture gotta go before a smooth knife can do it's thing.

Any reason you can't just throw another crown up there?

Comment: 1) I was trying to save the money on crown molding
2) The room is already going to be a nightmare for finish carpentry without the crown molding it has 2 45* short walls, a couple of recesses, 5 doors, and a window. I was hoping not to have to add crown molding on top of everything else.

What about calking it?

Comment: Also, the room is a converted sub basement to be used as a man cave. I don't expect it to come out perfect.

Comment: Here's an idea - tape it, block it, then apply another coat. Before top coat dries, run a broom over the mud horizontally, creating a texture detail. That way, it will look more purposeful.

Comment: I guess I am not following how that would be done, or what it would look like. Would it be like a stipple texture? http://www.home-repair-central.com/stipple-drywall-texture.html

Comment: Yes, very similar. Texturing is something you can practice with on cardboard on the floor, until you find the look you want.